# Random meme generator discord.js, glitch.com, node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js coding, I have been  trying to make a meme generator, any can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use npm packages to generate memes. 
for this command idea, I will use "random-discord"

- First of all , install `random-discord` by using **`npm i random-discord`** [random-discord Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-discord)
- and create new `random-discord` app with : 
  **`const { Random } = require('random-discord')`** 
  **`const random = new Random`**
- finally, Add this code to your bot main file :

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "meme") {
    let meme = await random.getMeme()
    message.channel.send(meme)
  }
})
```